# Consulta MySql delete from

Tags: mysql, sql

En la base de datos tengo.

```
Coches(matricula,año,modelo)
Es_Dueno(id_conductor,matricula)
Persona(id_conductor, nombre, direccion)
```

y quiero borrar el auto de modelo `Mazda` del cliente `Santos`

Hice la siguiente consulta:

```
DELETE FROM coches
    WHERE coches.matricula = (
        SELECT coches.matricula 
        FROM persona as A
        INNER JOIN es_dueno as B ON  A.id_conductor = B.id_conductor
        INNER JOIN coches ON B.matricula = coches.matricula 
        WHERE A.nombre ='Santos' AND coches.modelo = 'Mazda')
```

Y me retorna el siguiente error:

> 1093 - You can't specify target table 'Ej1_coches' for update in FROM clause

Comment: El error no corresponde a tu consulta. ¿Seguro que esa es la consulta que te da aquel error? ¿Qué es `Ej1_coches`?

Comment: @sstan suena raro no? Capaz es el nombre interno de la tabla.

Comment: @Pablo: Tal vez simplificó el nombre a `coches` al transcribir el ejemplo a su pregunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En base a la respuesta de @Pablo Claus, lo que puedes hacer es sacar la condición `coches.modelo = 'Mazda'` afuera de la subconsulta:

```
DELETE FROM coches
    WHERE coches.matricula IN (
        SELECT B.matricula 
        FROM persona as A
        INNER JOIN es_dueno as B ON  A.id_conductor = B.id_conductor
        WHERE A.nombre ='Santos')
    AND coches.modelo = 'Mazda'
```

Comment: Si, quería simplificar la pregunta y me olvidé de sacarle ese Ej1_coches.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me sirvió

Answer (score 4):

La guía de MySQL dice que

> You cannot delete from a table and select from the same table in a subquery.

No se puede borrar de una tabla y usar la misma tabla dentro de la subconsulta.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html

Por lo que, una opción sería obtener la matricula primero y después borrarla en otra consulta.